# Recursive Java RLE Decompression Method [stackoverflow error]

Tags: java, string, recursion, stack-overflow, compression

I am trying to write a program in Java that decompresses a compressed RLE statement using recursion, but I am continuously getting stack overflow errors and I do not know why.

Here is what I wrote thus far:

```
public class StringRec
{
    public static void main (String args[]){

        System.out.println(decompress("wed4d"));
    }
    //Version 0.1
    public static String decompress(String compressedText)
    {   String cText = compressedText; 
        StringBuffer newString = new StringBuffer();

        int i = 0;

        if (cText==""){return newString.toString();}

        if(!cText.isEmpty()){

            if(Character.isLetter(cText.charAt(i))){
                newString.append(cText.charAt(i));

                cText = cText.substring(1,cText.length());  

                return decompress(cText);
                //remove first letter, return new modified string with removed first letter to decompress.
            }
            if(Character.isDigit(cText.charAt(i))){
                 int c = cText.charAt(i)-'0';

                if (c==0){
                    cText = cText.substring(2,cText.length());}

                    return decompress(cText);   
                    //delete c and the letter after it and send new modified string to decompress.
                    }

                }else {
                    newString.append(cText.charAt(i+1));
                    int c = cText.charAt(i);
                    c--;
                    String num = ""+c;
                    cText = cText.replaceFirst(num, Character.toString(cText.charAt(i)));

                    return decompress(cText);
                    //appends character after number to newString, decrements the number and returns
                    //the new modified string to decompress with the first number decremented by one
                    }
        return newString.toString(); 

    }
}
```

My base case for the recursion is an empty string, if the string starts with a letter that letter is added to the stringbuffer newString only once and that first letter of the original string is deleted from the string sequence and the new string is passed to decompress; if it starts with a number that is zero then the first two chars of the string are deleted and the new string is passed to decompress.

If it's a number greater than 0[else] then the letter in front of it is added to the stringbuffer newString and the number is decremented and replaces the number in the beginning of the string and passes the new string [with the original first char number - 1] to decompress.

Comment: How long is the string? Java does not support unlimited recursion; recursive algorithms only work if they don't recurse too deep.

Comment: Don't know about the stack overflow, but every time you call `decompress` recursively, the recursive routine will create a **new** `newString`.  The new call of the routine will **not** append to the same `newString` that the old call was using.  Your recursive method will probably need to take `newString` as a parameter that it keeps passing to itself, and then an outside non-recursive routine will need to initialize it before calling the recursive routine for the first time.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger? That and a few well placed `System.out.println` logging calls would help you find out why your recursion is not reaching the base case and causing the error...

Comment: @user3003741 - i rolled back your last changes because it significantly changed the question & formatting, and included a new inappropriately named function at the end.  A different problem with new code should probably be posted as its own question. You may also want to consider the [StackOverflow chat system](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) for problems with a lot of back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the infinite recursion is occurring because of this:

```
int c = cText.charAt(i);
c--;
String num = ""+c;
cText = cText.replaceFirst(num, Character.toString(cText.charAt(i)));
```

If the character is `1`, then `c` will be 65, the ASCII value of the character `'1'`.  Then `num` will be set to the string `"64"`, and if there's no `"64"` in your string, the method will keep calling itself with the same string over and over.  Declaring `c` as a `char` should fix that.  Plus, note that `replaceFirst` says to search for a pattern that matches the first argument, and replace it with the second.  You may have this backwards.  Also, see my comment above about `newString`.

**EDIT:**To answer your comment: Using a StringBuffer is OK.  What you *cannot* do is have each `decompress` create a `new StringBuffer`, because then each time `decompress` is called a new `StringBuffer` will be created, which isn't what you want.  If `decompress` takes a `StringBuffer newString` parameter, and each time `decompress` calls itself it passes `newString` as a parameter, then every `decompress` call will point to the *same* `StringBuffer`, since it's a reference to an object.

The other approach that I think you hinted at was that since `decompress` returns a `String`, then every time `decompress` calls itself it can *use* the function result (right now your code is just throwing it away), and perhaps concatenate that function result with something else and return the new string.  I think you can make this approach work, but I haven't studied it thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it and will post the updated code. Can you further expand on the newString and the recursive routine? How would I go about doing that? Can I just change it up and have that string buffer be a normal String and I concatenate it.